# How to delete item in nested array to pass as react state

Tags: reactjs

In a react class called `CompanyDashboard` have a state called `data` that is an array 3 of objects, each of those objects has a `timeslots` key that holds an array of timeslots.

Inside `CompanyDashboard` I have a functional component called `CompanyPanel` that takes in the value of one company and renders the timeslots as a list of clicable items.

When i click on any of those items I execute a method called `deleteTime` from `CompanyDashboard` that is being passed to `CompanyPanel` as props, with `name` and `timeslot` as arguments.

I want to delete from the state called `data` the specific `timeslot` of the specific `company`, which I am getting in the `deleteTime` method as arguments.

But i dont know how.

On the stateless functional component I have this:

`<span className='pa2 red pointer ma2 bg-white' onClick={() => deleteTime(timeslot, company)}>X</span>`

and then in the `CompanyDashboard` this method:

```
deleteTime (timeslot, company) {

// here i want to remove the specific timeslot from the spcific company from the state data
// and set it to this new state without that specific item inside that specific company

}
```

The data state looks like this:

````
data = [
  {
    "_id": "5db581e58e11ad1b933e7f42",
    "name": "ZANITY",
    "times": [
      {
        "timestamp": 1474607824073,
        "dateUTCString": "Sat Sep 03 2016 19:01:09 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
      },
      {
        "timestamp": 1389120349942,
        "dateUTCString": "Mon Aug 19 2019 05:43:14 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5db581e584de79b380890f75",
    "name": "VETRON",
    "times": [
      {
        "timestamp": 1474607824073,
        "dateUTCString": "Sat Sep 03 2016 19:01:09 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
      },
      {
        "timestamp": 1389120349942,
        "dateUTCString": "Mon Aug 19 2019 05:43:14 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5db581e565b82e2b729077e1",
    "name": "KOZGENE",
    "times": [
      {
        "timestamp": 1474607824073,
        "dateUTCString": "Sat Sep 03 2016 19:01:09 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
      },
      {
        "timestamp": 1389120349942,
        "dateUTCString": "Mon Aug 19 2019 05:43:14 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
      },
    ]
  }
]```
````

Answer (score 0):

you should add a unique id to the time stamps objects so they would be more distinguishable and easier to deal with, but for now, we can do:

```js
deleteTime (timeslot, company) {
 const newState = state.map(company=>{
    company.times.filter(time=>{
      return time.timestamp !== timeslot
    })
    return company
  })

  this.setState(newState) // or setState(newState) if you are functional 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, thought I think it could be done in a simpler way, in any case it works:

```
  deleteTime (timeslot, name) {
    const newState = this.state.data.map(company => {
      if (name === company.name) {
        let newTimes = company.times.filter(time => {
          return time.dateUTCString !== timeslot.dateUTCString
        })
        company.times = newTimes
        return company
      }
      return company
    })
     this.setState({data: newState}) // or setState(newState) if you are functional 
  }
```